# How to change pages using JS keeping the navbar locked on top?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.mid {
    display: block;
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto auto;
}
.navbar {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}

.navbar li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 140%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="mid">
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/services.html">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

I want to go to the Services pages with the navbar locked on top. If the bar is fixed on top then called page should cover the rest of the screen.

Comment: do you mean change between sections in the **same** page ?

Comment: So you want to just change pages on a website and have the same navbar on each page?

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
.navbar {
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
}
```

this should hold the nav bar at the top of the page.